# fullScreen ImageView close

Tags: android, imageview

this is my code:

```
final ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
    imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageView1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        }
    });
```

by this code when i click on my ImageView i can see it in fullScreen.
Now i have a question:
when I see imageView in fullscreen I want when I press Back, this imageView close and back to previous situation and my app doesn't back to previous activity

Comment: You need to ask an actual question.

Answer (score 0):

Rather then opening an image on full screen you can use a custom dialog to open that image which is called a Full Image Dialog, which works exactly as AlertDialog, for that you just need to design a custom layout including width and height of image you are opening. It is easy to maintain as on clicking anywhere on screen dialog automatically closes and your activity will resume.
If you want then I can give you more idea?

Comment: I am beginner in android. please send code for me. thanks

Comment: ok, I'm writing code in my next answer giving you hint how you can implement it

Comment: if the above code worked for you then please approve the answer

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Make a class `FullImageDialog` having this method:

```
public static void showImage(Context context, String strImagePath) {
        AlertDialog.Builder imageDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_fullimage_dialog, null);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.fullImage);

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(strImagePath)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.default_user_image)
                .dontAnimate()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(image);
        //image.setImageDrawable(tempImageView.getDrawable());

        imageDialog.setView(layout);

        final AlertDialog alert= imageDialog.create();
        alert.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations=R.style.FadeInTheme;
        alert.show();
    }
```

Step 2: create xml of full_image_dialog as:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fullImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/default_user_image"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</LinearLayout>
```

step 3: call method where you need to open this dialog:

```
final ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
    imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
      //call FullImageDialog class by giving parameter of imageUrl
      FullImageDialog.showImage(imageUrl);

}
```